# What could we do with the [error] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, meta-tags

Well, we have a tag called [error](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error). Its description says:

> Please use a more specific tag instead.

Awesome. So what do [all these 547 questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error) have in common? A non-descriptive tag. On Oct. 10, @random even mentioned in the excerpt history:

> Let's stall this one if not outright kill it

I vote for killing it (with fire, of course). Nobody will ever use this tag – a lot of questions are only about error messages, and I can't imagine anybody using this tag as a favorite.

What do you think?

Comment: Sounds like a capital idea

Comment: Well, there *are* 4 followers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiery enough?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Could a ♦ *please* act on this?

- Nobody came forward in the defense of this tag in over a month
- [We already have rather well received duplicates for this topic](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3942/burninate-error-errors-fatal-error)
- Perfect +9/-0 score to the burn request

What more do we need?

Comment: Mods can't burn tags. Only developers can.

Comment: @Sathya Can you theoretically *un-tag* these for the time being?

Comment: @slhck by "un-tag" if you mean go and edit *each* question manually, then yes. There's no automated tool available to us to untag. We can mass-retag, not mass-untag/remove tag.

Comment: @Sathya Developers also have diamonds ;) Would be great if you or another moderator could request this through your contacts in the relevant circles though.