# Why has the Failure tag been resurrected?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The [failure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure) tag was [burninated in 2012](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3788/the-failure-tag-a-story-of-fail) since it doesn't add any value and could probably apply to half the questions on Superuser. Somehow there are now another 16 questions with the tag, including one from just a few days ago. Surely we need to banish the tag for good?

Comment: It was destroyed but not banned

Comment: It's a meta-meta tag - It failed at failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trogdor was fed with the same tag... twice. He's not quite happy repeating plate :/

Comment: In other words, [tag:status-completed]