# Burninate error, errors, fatal error

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What could we do with the [error] tag?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3736/what-could-we-do-with-the-error-tag)

I know this has been brought up already (the [error](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error) tag anyway), but it has still not been acted on, so I thought I would bring it up again.

At the very least, [errors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/errors) should be a synonym of [error](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error), but all three tags serve no real purpose.

Previous incarnations are [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3736/what-could-we-do-with-the-error-tag) and [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1648/are-error-and-problem-meta-tags).

Comment: I know you wrote it's been brought up before, but since the other topic (which you didn't link unfortunately) shows support of the community through up votes, I bumped it.

Comment: @DanielBeck, apologies, fixed now.